# Function that changes the cell color

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a function where if a cell has **Yellow** color and if I enter `0` in that cell, then it pops up a message box **Red** then colors the cell **Red**. And then if I enter `1` it reverts the color to **Yellow**.

Here's my code:

```
Function ColorChange(range)
    If range.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 And range.Value < 1 Then
        MsgBox "Project Delay!", vbCritical, "Attention required!"
        range.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    Else
        If range.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 And range.Value > 0 Then
            range.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Two questions **[1.]** Are you using this function as a UDF?  **[2.]** Have you considered using `Worksheet_Change` event?

Comment: im just trying dude , but i did it in change

Comment: I am trying to understand how are you calling that function (as a UDF? i.e from an excel cell?) If yes then you can also achieve what you want using the `Worksheet_Change` event :)

Comment: @Hotdog Have you tried `conditional formatting`?

Comment: @PaichengWu theres no like that in conditional formatting

Answer (score 0):

1) It is not necessary to use a function. In VBA you can program classically (and run the macro manually) or you can program event. It means that a macro will be running in case of a particular event (like a mouse-click or a modification in the sheet). That is why Siddarth Rout spoke about `Worksheet_change`, it is an event. In this case, define your Sub in this way and the following code will be executed in case of Worksheet modification.

2) You have to define a Private Sub for the specific worksheet. Private Sub `Worksheet_change()` and you put in argument `ByVal Target As range`. It means that you will receive information about the range that have been changed (Target).

3) After you will use `Target.Address` to define the range used by your code.

4) Your 2 intricate if statements are not necessary. It is better to use an if statement and an else if statement.

5) The following code is OK for me:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target As range)

If range(Target.Address).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 And range(Target.Address).Value < 1 Then
    MsgBox "Project Delay!", vbCritical, "Attention required!"
    range(Target.Address).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
ElseIf range(Target.Address).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 And range(Target.Address).Value > 0 Then
    range(Target.Address).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
End If

End Sub
```